# UWP: Cannot make ListView scrollable

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, scrollbar, vertical-scrolling

I have a page with a simple grid (2x2). In one grid on the bottom left corner is another Grid and inside this grid is a `ListView` bound to a collection. Entries can be added to the collection so the ListView grows in height (height of ListView is set to auto, so that all space available is used).

What I want is, if all available space (from the screen height) is used, scrollbars for the ListView should appear and should be usable. Funny (unfunny) thing is: scrollbars do appear but I cannot use them, I cannot scroll the ListView with the vertical scrollbar that appears when I hover the ListView.

It works, when I set the height of the ListView to a fixed value, but I don't want it that way, because then it doesn't use all the available space on the screen.

This is the XAML of the page (I removed some parts for demonstration purposes) :

```
<Page
    x:Class="Qooli.TimeTracker.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Qooli.TimeTracker"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        ...
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <StackPanel Name="spAddEntry" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30">
            <TextBlock Text="Add new entry:" Name="lblAddNewEntry" />
            ...
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30">
            <TextBlock Text="Allocated time:" Name="lblAllocatedTime" />
            ...
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="30">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Daily overview:" Name="lblDailyOverview" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
            <ListView Name="lvTimeEntries"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      Height="Auto"
                      MinHeight="100"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      MinWidth="300"
                      SelectionMode="Single"
                      ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.TimeEntriesAdvancedCollectionView, Mode=OneWay}"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled="True"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel></StackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:TimeEntry">
                        <Grid Background="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource TimeEntryTypeColorConverter}}" Padding="5">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="200"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Time, Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
                                       MinWidth="60"
                                       MaxWidth="60"
                                       Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title, Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                       MinWidth="100"
                                       MaxWidth="100"
                                       Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                            </TextBlock>
                            <Button Name="btnEditTimeEntry" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5,5,5,5">
                                <SymbolIcon x:Name="edit" Symbol="Edit"/>
                            </Button>
                            <Button Name="btnDeleteTimeEntry" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Margin="5,5,5,5">
                                <SymbolIcon x:Name="delete" Symbol="Delete"/>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource summaryTextStyle}" Text="Start time:" Name="lblDayStartTime" />
            ...
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Can someone spot why it is behaving this way?

Comment: The height of the grid row/cell is set to auto -> everything inside will get all space it needs. If you have enough space, why would you scroll?

Comment: So I should set a height for the rows of the Grid where the ListView is placed, or also for the other Grids (the main 2x2 Grid for example)?

Comment: Set the height of the second row to "*" for the both grids.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now as expected by setting height to "*" to the second grid row definitions. You should post your comments as answer, so I can accept them as answer.

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the height of the second row to `"*"` for both grids.